# Upload video to YouTube

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, youtube

I want to upload a video from my app to YouTube.

I understand that i need to use GData for this, and found some tutorials for this but the problem is that i don't found any new Documentation for this.

any idea if this class is good for iOS 6 too? and if there is any new API for upload video to YouTube from my iPhone app.

Comment: I search in google for this and read that GData support it,but i try to find a link to the project but didn't something that is not crashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all download GData sample project from below link:

`https://github.com/nparry/gdata-objectivec-client/tree/master/Source` 
Then try to search about how to send video from GData authentication. Then Add this Example

in App using following guidelines:

```
http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/
```

Try it hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use this library https://github.com/eternalstorms/ESSVideoShare-for-OS-X-Lion/wiki/How-To-for-iOS.
It allows you to upload to Youtube, Facebook & Vimeo.